# How do i grab an id from a collection_select form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I can see the the id inside the parameters in the log but i cant access it in the controller.Can any body please show me how else i could do?Apparently 
`@city=City.find(params[:cities][:city_id])` is not doing the job.Thank you

```
  <%= form_for :city, :url=>{:action =>"next"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:city_id, City.all, :id, :name ,:prompt=>"Select your city") %>

   <%=f.submit "continue" %>
   <%end%>
```

Home controller

```
       def next
       @city=City.find(params[:city_id]) 
       session[:city_id] = @city.id
       redirect_to :controller=>"parks",:action =>"show" 
       end
```

In the log

```
     Started POST "/home/next" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-10-21 12:16:37 -0700
     Processing by ParkController#show as HTML
     Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",  "authenticity_token"=>"7VVJ9GHcU4miYLCkSt91S674GGTScor86Tcsz7O25ik=", "city_id"=>"2",  "commit"=>"continue"}
     Rendered park/show.html.erb within layouts/header (2.5ms)
     Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awww damn Im an idiot didnt see it in the beginning. You wrote

```
@city=City.find(params[:cities])
```

But it should be

```
@city=City.find(params[:city_id])
```

Comment: Okay then please post a new version of the params has.

Comment: Are you perfectly sure there is a City with id=2 in your DB?

Answer (score 1):

You wrote

```
<%= collection_select(nil,:city_id, City.all, :id, :name ,:prompt=>"Select your city") %>
```

But you should write

```
<%= f.collection_select(:city_id, City.all, :id, :name ,:prompt=>"Select your city") %>
```

Like you did for the submit button! Actually you can also add this line to the forms target:

```
<%= params.inspect %>
```

to see which values are transfered in which hash.

Comment: thank you for pointing out that.i just changed like you advised but still i cant access it,see code above

Comment: Okay then retry to send the data and post the params hash.

Answer (score 1):

Umm, maybe I am wrong (not an experienced Rails dev), but don't you have to just write

```
params[:city_id]
```

?